# Need to pass a variable from JS to php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a title description for a chess eco code:

This is the lookup array in php named eco_codes:

```
 <?php
 $eco_tmp = array(
 "A00" => "Uncommon Opening 1.g4, a3, h3, etc.",
 "A01" => "Nimzovich-Larsen Attack 1.b3",
 "A02" => "Bird's Opening 1.f4",
 "A03" => "Bird's Opening 1.f4 d5")
 ?>
```

I have the lookup code (ex. GameECO = "A02") like this:

```
 <span id="GameECO"></span>
```

What I want is this:

```
 <?php $key = array_search($val['GameECO'], $eco_codes);?>

 <span id="GameECO" title = "<?php echo $key.$val['ECO']></span>
```

How can I proceed? Is php even required for this? Maybe js alone would do it?

my page is http://communitychessclub.com/basic.php?game=5312

Comment: How many codes are there?

Comment: @mplungjan there are 502 ECO codes

Comment: then put them in an external JS: `<script src="eco.js"></script>` or if they change dynamically `<script src="eco.php"></script>` where the php does a `header("content-type: text/javascript"=;`

Comment: @mplungjan I added <script src="eco-code"></script> and now I should be able to access "eco-code" array with js.  But it looks very complicated. Any hints?

Comment: The file name must end on `.js` if it is a static file

Comment: @mplungjan OK I added <script src = "eco-code.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the code in some variable, have a js file (ecocodes.js) containing

```
  var ecoCodes = { 
      "A00":"Uncommon Opening 1.g4, a3, h3, etc.",
      "A01":"Nimzovich-Larsen Attack 1.b3",
      "A02":"Bird's Opening 1.f4",
      "A03":"Bird's Opening 1.f4 d5"
    } // no comma after the last one
```

then you can use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chess</title>
    <script src="ecocodes.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload=function() {
        var eco = "A02";
        document.getElementById("GameECO").innerHTML=eco + ":"+ecoCodes[eco];
      }  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>  
  ECO: <span id="GameECO"></span>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

It works like this:

```js
  var ecoCodes = { 
      "A00":"Uncommon Opening 1.g4, a3, h3, etc.",
      "A01":"Nimzovich-Larsen Attack 1.b3",
      "A02":"Bird's Opening 1.f4",
      "A03":"Bird's Opening 1.f4 d5"
    } // no comma after the last one

window.onload=function() {
    var eco = "A02";
    document.getElementById("GameECO").innerHTML=eco + ":"+ecoCodes[eco];
}
```

```html
ECO: <span id="GameECO"></span>
```